# Картинки появляются после обновления страницы php + mysql

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, изображения

Суть такая, залил сайт на хостинг. При первом заходе картинки на сайте не прогружаются (которые вызываются php кодом), но как только обновляешь страницу, они появляются. Я так понимаю в первую загрузку они загружаются в кеш, а во вторую уже берутся оттуда. Как можно исправить это?

```
<?php 
$user = 'данныеюзера';
$pass = 'данныепаса';
$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'датабаза';
$dbh = 'mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db.';charset=utf8';
$pdo = new PDO($dbh, $user, $pass);
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Что-то пошло не так");
}
?>

<?php require_once './public/header.php';?>



<?php 
$about = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM about");
$about->execute();
$result =$about->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
?>

  <main class="main">
    <section class="description">
      <h1 class="description__title"><?php echo $result->name ?></h1>
      <div class="description__content-container">
        <div class="description__image-container">
          <img class="description__image" src="./admin/img/<?php echo $result->filename ?>" alt="Картинка описания" style="border-radius: 10%; width: 200px; height: 100px;">
        </div>
        <div class="description__text-container">
          <h2 class="description__subtitle"><?php echo $result->title ?></h2>
          <p class="description__text"><?php echo $result->subtitle ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    
<?php require_once './public/cities.php';?>
<?php require_once './public/footer.php';?>
```

Answer (score 1):

У тебя код, как буд-то из адской пещеры вывалился. И хочет съесть чей-то мозг )

```php
try {
  $pdo = new PDO($dbh, $user, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $err) {
  die("Ошибка БД: " . $err->getMessage());
}
require_once './public/header.php';
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM about");
$statement->execute();

$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo '<main class="main">';
foreach ($results as $result):
?>

...HTML...
  
<?php
endforeach;
echo '</main>'; # забыл =)
require_once './public/cities.php';
require_once './public/footer.php';
?>
```